# Event Listener in react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-listener

Essentially, I have this function component, but I'm struggling with adding the listener just to this component, since right now it's going to the entire window. I tried using useRef, but that wasn't working. Any ideas?

````
const  AddReply =({item })=> {
        const {replies, setReplies, artists, setArtists, messages, setMessages, songs, setSongs, posts, setPosts, likes, setLikes, user, setUser, accesstoken, setAccesToken, refreshtoken, setRefreshtoken} = React.useContext(InfoContext);

        const refKey = useRef();
        function eventhandler(e) {
                if (e.code === 'Enter') {
                 handleSubmitReply();
                 console.log("Works");
               }
            }

        function handleSubmitReply(){
                console.log(document.getElementById("textareareply").value);
                const likesref=dbLikes.push(0);
                const likeskey=likesref.getKey();
                console.log("Likes key is ", likeskey);
               
                const ref = dbReplies.child(item['replies']).push({
                  'content':document.getElementById("textareareply").value,
                  'posterid': user.id,
                  'likes': likeskey,
                  "createdAt": {'.sv': 'timestamp'}
                });
            
              }
        useEffect(() => {
          
      // if I were to use useRef, then I tried using ref.current,
      // but then I got that "TypeError: refKey.current.addEventListener 
      // is not a function". 
          window.addEventListener("keyup", eventhandler);
          return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("keyup", eventhandler);
          };
        }, []);
      
        return(
                    
        <div>
                <TextArea id="textareareply" ref={refKey} rows={1} placeholder='Reply to post' /> 
                <Form.Button fluid positive onClick = {()=>handleSubmitReply()} style={{marginTop:"10px"}}>Reply</Form.Button> 
       </div>
)}

export default AddReply;```
````

Comment: Did [keyUp](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events) not work? `<TextAreay onKeyUp={eventhandler}`

Answer (score 1):

Your `useRef` doesn't work probably because `<TextArea>` is a functional component so can't use `ref`. Instead, attach `ref` to the container:

```
      <div ref={refKey}>
          <TextArea id="textareareply" rows={1} placeholder='Reply to post' /> 
          <Form.Button fluid positive onClick = {()=>handleSubmitReply()}
                  style={{marginTop:"10px"}}>Reply</Form.Button> 
       </div>
```

Then you can now attach event to it:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        const div = refKey.current;
        div.addEventListener("keyup", eventhandler);
        return () => {
            div.removeEventListener("keyup", eventhandler);
        };
    }, []);
```

That should solve your problem, but if you still prefer the current way of listening on `window` without `useRef`, then just add logic to the event handler to act only on your component:

```js
    function eventhandler(e) {
        if (e.target.getAttribute('id') === 'textareareply') {            
            if (e.code === 'Enter') {
                console.log("Works");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When we use a functional component, we pass directly the function reference into DOM event attributes, such as:

```js
function AddReply() {
    
    function handleButtonClick(event) {
        console.log(event)
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={handleButtonClick}> Click Here </button>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) This helped me solve my issue.